# PHP URL Encoding/Decoding Pretty Quotes across form field's %u2019

Tags: php, forms, encoding, quotes, decoding

For some reason, after submitting a string like this `Jack’s Spindle` from a text form to php, I get:

`Jack%u2019s Spindle`

This is *not* what PHP's `urlencode()` would do, which would be `Jack%92s+Spindle`
or `rawurlencode()` = `Jack%92s%20Spindle`

Thus, `urldecode()` and the raw version don't work to decode that string... Is there another function for such strings?

--

Also, `Jack&#8217;s Spindle` would be the HTML-safe way to encode the above, but `urlencode()` and raw* for that yields: `Jack%26%238217%3Bs+Spindle` and `Jack%26%238217%3Bs%20Spindle` respectively...

Where is the `%u2019` coming from? What does it represent? How do you get it back to just that innoculous apostrophe?

Comment: similar encoding confusion arises for `“Surrounded Pretty Quotes”`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, only you can tell us from where that came from. From are you getting your text and which transformations is it being submitted to? I confess I haven't seen that encoding strategy yet.

That said, it's very similar to the way Javascript encodes UTF-16 code units: `\uXXXX` where each `X` represents a hexadecimal character. To convert it to HTML entities, you could do:

```
preg_replace('/%u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})/', '&#x\\1;', $string)
```

Answer (score 3):

The Regular Expression in the `preg_replace` function call should have an ending delimiter, i.e: `preg_replace('/%u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})/', '&#x\\1;', $string)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of problem. 
When i send variable via javascript/ajax to a php script, the php was displaying %u2019 instead of quote, etc...
I solved it like this :
- in my javascript script, replacing `escape(myvar)` by `encodeURIComponent(myvar)` before sending
- in my php file, using `$myvar=utf8_decode($_POST['myvar'])`

Hope thant can help.